# Can an amount of money be equivalent to a product?

Tags: money

The concept of money as the measure of value is weird to me. Let's assume a loaf of bread is 2 dollars in price.

Thus we have this equation: a loaf of bread = 2 dollars

However, according to the equation, the wage of me, which is 6 dollars, can be paid by giving me 3 loaves of bread. An 8-dollar hat can be paid by using 4 loaves of bread. And my savings are 10 dollars, which can be changed to 5 loaves. This is all because a loaf of bread and 2 dollars are equivalent in value as shown in the equation above.

However, we all know this is non-sense. 2 dollars is not equivalent to one loaf of bread. 2 dollars allows me to get different things while a loaf of bread is just food. They are not equivalent. But sometimes people accept things or services as a payment as if seeing them as money. For example, a person owes someone two dollars. Maybe he would accept a loaf of bread that is sold for 2 dallors as a payment. The reason seems to be he thinks that the bread is equivalent to the money, but this contradicts my reasoning above.

Why is that? Maybe this equation only applies in certain conditions?

Comment: [Equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) is not the same as identity. It means matching in some limited sense, two things can be "equivalent" if they have the same color, for example. Equivalence here just means that some goods or services can be exchanged for each other (or a sum of money) in some ideal market conditions, nothing more. If you can sell the loaf of bread for $2 then it gets you whatever $2 gets you on the market.

Comment: Money is not a physical thing: it is an "abstract" like numbers. This is why we exchange thing whose **value** is x with an x amount of money. See [Theory of value (economics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_value_(economics)).

Comment: The value of an item is subjective, in that it will have a different value to different people, depending on their wants. Also, its value depends on how much you already have. If you are dying of thirst, you might be willing to trade everything you have for a bottle of water, but if you have plenty already, the marginal value of an extra bottle of water is quite small. The concepts of subjective value and marginal value were worked out over 100 years ago by Carl Menger and Eugen Bohm-Bawerk.

Answer (score 0):

Money doesn't spoil like a loaf of bread. Money is much easier to exchange for things, than a loaf. Whereas the kind of swaps you talk about are in what is called 'the informal economy', where people negotiate one-off trades - it can be considered tax avoidance. There is 'legal tender', local currency backed by law. There are many [theories of value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_value_(economics)#Theories), to account for the ways we behave.

For an anthropologist's take on the origins of money, see Graeber's [Debt: The First 5000 Years](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debt:_The_First_5000_Years). Barter is a lot less common in history and now, than many economists think. It tends to only occur substantially in economies with established use of currency, but hyperinflation or war making it's use problematic. Fundamentally, money is a promise from a society or community with a shared currency, that the store of value will be honoured for future exchange.

Comment: "Money doesn't spoil like a loaf of bread." -- During the Weimar inflation you needed a barrel of money to buy a loaf of bread. I'm sure you've seen the famous photos. Coming soon to a bankrupt empire near you. Here's an article about the inflationin Venezuela. https://www.thedailybeast.com/thanks-to-hyperinflation-in-venezuela-you-need-a-wheelbarrow-of-cash-to-buy-bread/1